# Controller value not updating after async factory call (FB API)

Tags: angularjs

I'm building a custom AngularJS factory that deals with Facebook user authentication.

In my controller I am binding to the `FBUser` object but my view is not outputting anything for `{{user.name}}`. However, if I wrap the controller block in a 1 second `$timeout` then it works. I thought `$rootScope.$apply()` would trigger my view to update with the new FBUser values but it doesn't. Ideally I want to do as little work within the controller as possible because in future I want other model controllers in my app to make use of the user object from the factory.

```
angular.module('tatsdb.fbauth', ['tatsdb.api'])

.factory('FBAuth', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  var FBUser = {};
  var FBAuth = {};

  FBAuth.authResponseChange = function() {
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        FBAuth.getUserAsync();
      }
      else {
        console.log('not connected');
      }
    });
  };

  FBAuth.getUserAsync = function() {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
      $rootScope.$apply(function() {
        FBUser = response;
      });
    });
  };

  FBAuth.getUser = function() {
    return FBUser;
  };

  FBAuth.logout = function() {
    FB.logout(function(response) {
      FBUser = {};
    });
  };

  return FBAuth;
}])

.run(['$window', 'FBAuth',
  function($window, FBAuth) {
    $window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '278156419011935',
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
      });

      FBAuth.authResponseChange();
    };

    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));
}])

.controller('FBUserController', ['$scope', 'FBAuth', function($scope, FBAuth) {
  $scope.user = FBAuth.getUser();
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say skip the `controller` and just have `FBUser` on your scope and change your async function to:

```
FBAuth.getUserAsync = function() {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
        FBUser = response;
    });
  };
```

This way, the `FBUser` variable is on your scope and would get updated with the response. Also, you won't need to do `{{user.name}}` and you'll just have `{{FBUser.name}}`.

The reason you're not getting the name at the moment is because the controller function executes **before** you're getting the response. That's also why wrapping it in a 1 second timeout would do the trick most of the times, but that's no solution obviously.

Comment: How should I have FBUser, a variable declared inside the factory, on my scope? Do I just write {{FBUser.name}} in my view?

I understand the controller is executing before getting the response which is the main reason for this question really. How could I go about updating the view once FBUser.name is populated?

Comment: @Fenda I myself would use a service. That service would hold a member `FBUser`, which would be assigned the response that you get from the API. Then in my controller, I'd do `$scope.FBUser = facebookApiService.FBUser;` and in the view I'll do `{{FBUser.name}}`. I haven't worked with factories yet, I find it much easier and more intuitive to use a service.

Comment: Isn't that basically what I am already doing? FBUser is being assigned the response from the API and I was binding to it from the Controller. As far as I can see using a service or a factory is the same here.

Comment: @Fenda Another thing that can help you (solved the same issue for me several times) is have `FBUser` under another parameter in the scope. For instance, `$scope.User.FBUser = FBAuth.getUser();` and then in your view `{{User.FBUser.name}}`.

Comment: I tried switching to a Service and what you suggested but it's not working. The issue is still that the controller is being executed before the FBUser is populated. We need to tell the view somehow that FBUser was updated?

Comment: @Fenda Did you try to put it under another variable like I suggested in the last comment?

Comment: Yes, here is a JSFiddle using that. You can use the Login button with a test app I made and in the console you'll see "Good to see you, <name>" but the value inside `{{User.FBUser.name}}` doesn't update.

Comment: @Fenda Where's the fiddle ? :)

Comment: @Fenda Am I supposed to do anything besides click the log in button? I get this when I click it: `App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login.`

Comment: I had to make the app public so that non-admins could use it. Could you try again? The login button should work.

Comment: @Fenda This is what I'm getting in console: `Good to see you, Omri Aharon.` So that means it works doesn't it?

Comment: That means you've logged in to Facebook successfully. But if you look at the HTML it doesn't update with your name. It still says just `Name:`. It should say `Name: Omri Aharon`.